# Variable in C not printing the given value

Tags: c, variables, compiler-errors, compilation, integer

Alright, so basically recently I started studying C as a hobby, and I wanted to create a small program.Everything works fine, but when I make the variable "Age" like this:

```
int myAge = "14";
printf("My age is%d\n", myAge);
```

It prints out 1642.
I have tried switching to

```
printf('My age is%i\n', age);
```

But it did the same.
I also tested changing the number to a string but it obviously failed, because this isn't Python.
Anybody can help?

Comment: Why are you using double quotes?

Comment: C is not something you can learn by trial and error. Pick up some beginners C book, or find some tutorials in the internet.

Comment: `int myAge = "14";` --> `int myAge = 14;` Done...

Comment: When you wrote `int myAge = "14"`, did your compiler not give you a warning or error message?  (Mine says "incompatible pointer to integer conversion".)  If your compiler didn't complain about that line, you need to get a better compiler -- there are lots of simple mistakes you can make while learning C, that a good compiler will warn you about, that will be badly confusing otherwise.

Comment: "But it did the same." Well, no! This will never ever do the same. `'My age is%i\n'` is a multi-byte character literal which has type `int` and an implementation defined value. That is nothing even close to a format string. If your program did the same then probably because it did not compile and you executed the old binary from earlier compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Perhaps receive a warning like:

> warning: initialization of 'int' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

---

`int myAge = "14";` sets `myAge` to the address of the [*string literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) `"14"`.

Instead, initialize with an `int`.

```
int myAge = 14;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fixed version of your program. Just declaring the age variable as an integer is enough to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int age = 14;
  printf("My age is %d", age);
}
```

Friendly note:
C is not like Python. Arrays don't work the same, strings don't exist, and programming in C is fundamentally different in every way. I would advise that you definitely take a course rather than trying to teach yourself from scratch.

Comment: "strings don't exist," is unclear as C lib specially defines _string_ and uses that extensively throughout its spec.  C spec also has _string literal_.  Perhaps you meant to say Python and C define _string_ differently?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah you're right that's what I meant. I should've said that strings don't exist in the traditional sense and that in C, strings are character arrays. Thanks chux (:

Comment: Hmmm, "in the traditional sense"?  As C been around since 1973 or so years and  Python since 1991, one could assert Python is using the non-traditional one.  OTOH Lisp (created in 1958) may use another _string_ def.  Otherwise, nice basic answer

Answer (score 0):

u should write `int myAge = 14` , writting 14 in double quotes means its a string (thx HAL)

Comment: `"14"` is a a string, not a character or an integer.  Technically it is an array `char [3]` with  content `{49, 52, 0}`. And by the way, a character in C *is* a type of integer.

Answer (score -1):

We use double quotes when we have string and single quote when we have character but 14 is an integer we should write `int myAge=14;` or if u want "14" u should write `char myAge[2]="14";` then `printf("%s",myAge);`

Comment: `"%s"` expects `myAge` to point to a _string_. `char myAge[2]` is not a string as it lacks a _null character_.

Comment: meAge[] initialized to "14" so it is a string. we don't need character to become a string

Comment: Bilel kort, `"14"` is a string, a string literal of 3 `char`.  `char myAge[2]` is not a string as there is no _null character_.   In C, a _string_ contains and ends with a _null character.  C lib: "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.".